# JavaScript - check if input date is within add 7 days from current yyyy/mm/dd date, NOT js date()

Tags: javascript, date

I have a form submit with 2 date inputs: `share_start` and `share_end` in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. I use JS to validate the input and want to check whether `share_end` date is within 7 days from the `share_start` date.

Now, the tricky bit is that I don't have a JS `date()` dates/timestamps, but only those input dates, but when trying to add on 7 days to the input in JS all I end up with an error since JS needs to operate with `date()`. I cannot use any external scripts like `moment.js` to help with this.

Does JS have some sort of in-built function like PHPs `strtotime` where I can just add `+ 7 days` or something?

Thank you

```
// Form Submit Validation
function validateForm() {
    var share_start = '2021-05-07';
    var share_end = '2021-05-15';
    var share_max = share_start.setDate(date.getDate() + 6);
    
    if (share_end > share_max) {
        alert("Share End Date cannot be more than 7 days from now");
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: without `Date` and without external libraries? no. Even external libraries will use `Date` internally

Comment: how about converting the input `share_start` and `share_end` to JS `date()` and comparing them then?

Comment: That is a good idea. What are the values of `share_start` and `share_end`?

Comment: for example `2021-05-07` and `2021-05-09`.

Comment: That looks like a valid ISO date string? why not have a go at using `Date` and then update the ticket with a [mcve] if it goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last figured it out.... Bloody JS date conversion is really a pain without libraries such `moments.js`

```
var date1 = '2021-01-01';
var date2 = '2021-01-08';
var diffTime = Math.abs(date2 - date1);
var diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

if (diffDays > 6) {
    alert("Share cannot be longer than 6 days");
    return false;
}
```

In my particular case, I am getting the date values from a variable, which I then calculate the difference in seconds, after which I convert those seconds to days. Followed by a simple if statement where I check if the value is greater than x days, and I am good to go.

Comment: `diffTime` is `NaN`? This answer doesn't seem to be valid?